# How to install ChromeDriver on Azure app serveice (Linux)

Tags: java, azure, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I implemented Java code to scrape data using chromedriver. My OS is Windows and the app service that I have is Linux. I put both chromedriver.exe (for windows) and chromedriver (for linux) in the resources folder.
I am able to run the code on Windows locally and it works but when I try to run the scraper on app service, it gives me an error as:

```
lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /src\main\resources\chromedriver
```

Code trials:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

Is there a way that I can install/move the driver to a place in linux that I be able to run my code in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

As your *OS is Windows and the app service is Linux based*, keeping both chromedriver.exe (for windows) and chromedriver (for linux) in the resources folder isn't a recommended practice.

Tests should be either [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) based or [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) based. So only the optimum resources should only be shared within the *`resources`* directory.

The bottom line is, if *chromedriver.exe* is not a part of your tests, you should totally remove it from the *`resources`* directory and execute your tests with the recommended executables/libraries.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't work in Linux. It throws an exception as I mentioned. Should I specify a certain config?